# Angular UI not updating after Observable subscription triggers

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, angular-changedetection

I have an angular page that uses an observable parameter from a service. However when this observable updates, the page is not updated to match.

I have tried storing the result of the observable in a flat value, or altering a boolean to adjust the UI, but none seem to have any effect.

Logging the observable confirms that it does update correctly, and on re-navigating to the page the new value is shown.

Other conditional UI updates correctly modify the page, only one below (`*ngIf="(entries$ | async), else loading"`) is causing this issue.

**component.ts**

```
export class EncyclopediaHomeComponent implements OnInit {
  entries$: Observable<EncyclopediaEntry[]>;
  categories$: Observable<string[]>;
  entry$: Observable<EncyclopediaEntry>;
  entry: EncyclopediaEntry;
  isEditing: boolean;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private encyService: EncyclopediaService) {
    this.entries$ = encyService.entries$;
    this.categories$ = encyService.categories$;

    this.entries$.subscribe(es => {
      console.log(es);
    });

    route.url.subscribe(url => this.isEditing = url.some(x => x.path == 'edit'));
    this.entry$ = route.params.pipe(
      switchMap(pars => pars.id ? encyService.getEntry(pars.id) : of(null)),
    );
    this.entry$.subscribe(entry => this.entry = entry);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  updateEntry(entry: EncyclopediaEntry) {
    this.encyService.updateEntry(entry.id, entry);
  }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="encyclopedia-container">
    <ng-container *ngIf="(entries$ | async), else loading">
        <app-enc-list [entries]="entries$ | async"
            [selectedId]="entry ? entry.id : null"></app-enc-list>

        <ng-container *ngIf="entry">
            <app-enc-info *ngIf="!isEditing, else editTemplate"
                [entry]="entry$ | async"></app-enc-info>

            <ng-template #editTemplate>
                <app-enc-edit [entry]="entry$ | async" [categories]="categories$ | async"
                    (save)="updateEntry($event)"></app-enc-edit>
            </ng-template>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #loading>
        <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
        <br>
        <p>Loading Encyclopedia...</p>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

edit: 
**service.ts**

```
export class EncyclopediaService {
  entriesSubject = new ReplaySubject<EncyclopediaEntry[]>();
  entries$ = this.entriesSubject.asObservable();
  private _entries: EncyclopediaEntry[];

  constructor(private file: FileService) {
    file.readFromFile(this.projectName+'Encyclopedia').subscribe((es: string) => {
      this._entries = JSON.parse(es);
      this.entriesSubject.next(this._entries);
      this.entries$.subscribe(es => this.file.writeToFile(this.projectName+'Encyclopedia', JSON.stringify(es)));
    });
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: Did you change the change detection strategy?

Comment: @sloth I have not. I've also tried setting it to Default manually, to no effect.

Comment: @Pac0 I have tried that (only for entries$ which is causing the issue), and the result appears exactly the same.

Comment: @Pac0 should not be an issue since the component it comes from has no way to erase the entry, but it's something I'll keep my eye on

Comment: The two subscriptions do not affect each other or the same part of the code so it does not matter which completes first. It is something I will clean up later though.

Comment: I am not sure what `file.readFromFile`, but if you wrap its callback with `ngZone.run` it should work without "hack" further down the line. Also you can do `entries$: Observable<<EncyclopediaEntry[]> = this.entriesSubject;`

Comment: As usual, the issue is not where I was looking. That solves the issue as well. Even something that I thought about, just not at the root of the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the component does not see changes.
I do not know why because |async will do this job.

but to fix it you can use ChangeDetector:

```js
constructor(
   private route: ActivatedRoute,  
   private encyService: EncyclopediaService
   private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
) {
    this.entries$ = encyService.entries$;
    this.categories$ = encyService.categories$;

    this.entries$.subscribe(es => {
      // setTimeout need to run without troubles with ng changes detector
      setTimeout(_=>{this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()},0);
      ...
    });
```

or 
you can use markforCheck like it described [there](https://medium.com/@gregor.srdic/changedetectorref-markforcheck-vs-detectchanges-c5996267a2cb).

Comment: This works :) I had tried ChangeDetectorRef before but not with the setTimeout.

As it's a bit of a fudgy solution, I'll try the markForCheck method as well, and wait to see if there's another solution. If not, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Also, if any else knows why change detection isn't noticed, even if it's not a fixable cause, it would be appreciated.

Comment: @Dant To see why it is not detected we need the code that creates the `entries$` observable, it is somehow created outside of anguar

Comment: For future reference: this solution caused routing warnings when clicking links accessible through this result. Also caused issues in some observables in child components. Wrapping the `setTimeout()` inside `ngZone.run()` fixed this.

Comment: in my case, I have a module, inside module I'm use Component to routerLink, and inside component I use much component to make it easy to manage. using setTimeout and changeDetectorRef working for me